# Android Lollipop camera issue

Tags: android, bitmap, android-5.0-lollipop

My android application was working fine on all android devices from version 2.3 to 4.4. However, when i updated my Samsung Galaxy S4 to LOLLIPOP and tested the said app, there are a few errors in functionalities such as camera,map etc.

Below is the code snippet used in my application to utilize the native camera:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult( requestCode,  resultCode,  data);
   if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
   {    
      Bitmap camImg = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
   }
}
```

Here I am getting (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data") as null. Is there any alternate solution for this code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show your `startActivityForResult()` call.

Comment: I am using a custom action sheet. Please see the below code.
 
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
      android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to be following the documentation, and it would appear that the camera app that is being chosen here is not.

This is one of the risks in delegating work like this to a third-party app -- third-party apps can have bugs.

Your choices are:

1. Switch to using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to specify a `Uri` for a full-size image. In your results, if you do not have the `data` `Bitmap`, try reading in the full-size image, using `BitmapFactory.Options` to down-sample it to something more appropriately sized. There may still be camera apps that honor `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` that do not work, but it should reduce the number of such broken apps.
2. Use the `android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2` APIs yourself, and avoid relying upon a third-party app.

Comment: Thanks Mark Murphy. Will try this and let you know.

Between why this question is downvoted. Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @prijin: "Between why this question is downvoted. Just asking out of curiosity" -- I have no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to disagree with CommonsWare on this one. I am using the android.hardware.Camera with my app and testing with a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Lollipop. It seems the problem is that onCreate is called before onActivityResult when running the app on Samsung Lollipop.

My suggestion is to set the max target in your app to 20 (Android 4.4) until Samsung sorts this out. It is a Samsung issue.

```
 android:maxSdkVersion="20"
```