# Compression of image not working

Tags: android, image, amazon-s3, imageview, image-compression

I am trying to upload picture using camera. I am uploading it to server

1. Clicking image and showing it in imageview ( DONE)
2. Compressing the image size to upload        (Not Working)
3. Uploading image to S3 (with uncompressed image)   (DONE)

   This is my onActivityResult()

   ```
       case CAMERA_REQUEST: {

           Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
           String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                   filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();

           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
           String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
           cursor.close();

           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
           BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
           int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
           int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
           String imageType = options.outMimeType;
               options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,200,100);//512 and 256 whatever you want as scale
               options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
           Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);

           File pngDir = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PicUploadTemp");
           if (!pngDir.exists()) {
               pngDir.mkdirs();
               }

         File pngfile = new File(pngDir,"texture1.jpg");
           FileOutputStream fOut;

           try {
                   fOut = new FileOutputStream(pngfile);

                    yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50,fOut);


           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pngfile.getPath().toString());
           rlLayout.setBackground(d);

           yourSelectedImage.recycle();
       //    resizedBitmap.recycle();

           xfile = pngfile; 
       }
       break;
   ```

---

```
cam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Copy logcat and paste it here (edit your answer)

Comment: Maybe this links can help: 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768145/what-data-is-returned-when-using-action-image-capture

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145976/android-lollipop-camera-issue

Comment: 'Compressing the image size to upload ' ??? What do you want to do? Compress or resize?

Comment: @greenapps I want to capture an image and upload it after Compressing it

Comment: It makes no sence to compress a .jpg file as it is allready compressed.

Comment: the file size is 1.5-2 MB , it will take 90 seconds to upload that image ....

Comment: What do you want to say with that? You would like to compress/zip it. But that will not do as it is a .jpg. Your only option is to resize it before uploading. Or upload it in a lesser quality.